# Efficient way to get the average value in a neighborhood of pixel, on mesh grid

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

My problem is quite complex but I'm not sure how can I split it.

I have the image and I'd like to put a grid (mesh grid?) on it, and then get the average color of the pixel on line crossings and its neighborhood.

The image below illustrates my task:

[image]

So eventually I want to know whether the stone is black, white, or the position is empty.

My question is how to efficiently get the pixel in the red area?

The vanilla solution is

```
x = np.linspace(0, image.shape[0], 19)
y = np.linspace(0, image.shape[1], 19)

for i in x:
    for j in y:
        color = image[i, j, :]
```

But it's not efficient and doesn't average within the neighborhood. There will also be some problems with

Comment: if the neigjborhoods look the same (the regions) you can create a single mask and use subimages. Should be quite efficient and simple to implement, but probably there are more efficient solutions if neighborhoods intersect, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The solution doesn't seem to support the task all that well.  Yes, averaging the neighborhood color is one metric of the image there -- but as you say, it's inefficient.

You don't need the neighborhood: you need the stone classification.  You could do this with a single pixel, or a handful, in areas that do not get overlaid with annotation information such as the move number.

From the intersection point, simply grab a pixel at, say, the 1:00 direction, 90* of the radius from the center.  Adjust as needed for the line width.  For instance, given a position `(row, col)` and stone radius `r`

```
x = col + 0.85 * r
y = row + 0.10 * r
color = image[x, y, :]
brightness = sum(color)
if brightness < 100:
    stone = "black"
elif brightness > 600:
    stone = "white"
else:
    stone = "vacant"
```

Comment: I need to average a few pixels because the images will be real photos with noise etc. 
So your advice is to not define the points before calculations (using f.e. linspace)? I thought it will be more efficient to work on matrices and take care of all the points "at once"

Comment: Your example is *not* a real photo; it's a representation of a GUI game board.  If you have noise in your photos, then the quantity of points you need is dependent upon the amount of noise.  Your base problem is that you're sampling far more points than you need.